# Performance of Raspberry Pi 4B Bullseye VNC headless

Tags: pi-4, vnc, performance, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I have headless Raspberry Pi 4B 4GB Bullseye connected over USB-C to iPad Pro and I am using VNC to connect to it directly over a USB-C cable which also powers it. I have increased GPU memory to 256 and I am at 1024 resolution. However the performance of the system over VNC is unusable.

I have noticed that the performance gets fluent if I use raspi-config to switch to composite video but that of course has resolution limit to 720 which is too small and it displays as a small view in a corner of the iPad.

I have also tried switching to NoMachine but it doesn’t seem to help.
I have bought the Raspberry to be used this way with my iPad but I can’t seem to resolve the performance issue. Can you please advice?

Comment: Seems to be related to video drivers that came with Bullseye update. I switched to Twister OS 32 bit and there is no issue with it, great to work with.

Comment: I've used NoMachine at 1920x1080 on a Pi 4 connected via Cat8 ethernet and that's fine..

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, it works perfect, once you update the drivers it becomes extremely slow, So install a fresh OS and don't update the video drivers until they are fixed
I have tried a few suggestions on the web, for some it worked, but for me, none of them worked. Only fresh install and no updates.